# Select files with similar names

Tags: java, android, file

I'm searching for a script that allow to select multiple files with similar name.
I've got 10 files:

1. hello.myapp-1.apk
2. hello.myapp-2.apk
3. hello.myapp-3.apk
4. hello.myapp-4.apk
5. other.ot
6. ...
7. ...
8. ...
9. ...
   10....

i want select the files from hello.myapp-1.apk to  hello.myapp-4.apk. Is possible to do with only one line of code like this ?

```
File su6 = new File("/dir/app/hello.myapp-*.apk");
```

Comment: File denotes one file, not multiple files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
File dir = new File("/dir/app/");
File [] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.startsWith("hello.myapp-") && name.endsWith(".apk");
    }
});

for (File file : files) {
    //do stuff with file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
File[] result = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
      return name.startsWith("hello.myapp-");//or use contains, regex/matcher etc
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
  File su6 = new File("/dir/app/hello.myapp-" + i + ".apk");
```

Comment: Too localised solution. Answers just the specific case.

Comment: i think this can be a simple solution for this case. (but... not the best of corse)